# How can I get "innerHTML" with Regex?

Tags: c#, html, regex, html-parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

`<a href="http://abc.com/abc.htm" style="color:#005F9A;">I need it</a>`

How can i get "I need it" sentence? I want use regular expression...

Comment: If you need to parse HTML, use HtmlAgilityPack http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

Here's the regex pattern that you can use to extract what you want:

```
(?<=\<a\shref=.*?\>).*?(?=\<\/a\>)
```

Comment: FYI, `<`, `>` and `/` have no special meanings and do not need to be escaped.  Also, lookarounds are an unnecessary complication; it's much simpler as well as more efficient to match the whole element "straight" and extract its content via a capturing group.